# "Au jeudi" ou "à jeudi"?

Tags: prépositions, articles, indications-de-temps

J'ai vu l'expression suivante à propos d’un journal télévisé:

> Du lundi au jeudi à 19h30.

Pourquoi ne dit-on pas

> De lundi à jeudi à 19h30.

au lieu de cela ? Quand on veut dire qu'on va se revoir jeudi, on dit

> À jeudi !

et non pas

> Au jeudi !

Alors, dit-on

> La construction durera jusqu'au jeudi.

ou

> La construction durera jusqu'à jeudi.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je crois qu'on dit "du lundi au jeudi" lorsqu'on parle en général  :

> Le club est ouvert toute l'année du lundi au jeudi.

et "de lundi à jeudi" lorsqu'on parle d'une semaine en particulier:

> Je serai absent de lundi à jeudi.

Alors on dira:

> La construction durera jusqu'à jeudi.

Comment: Quand on précise la date, on doit aussi dire *du/au* : ***je serai absent du lundi 8 au jeudi 11***.

Comment: Pour ajouter une nuance: Souvent, les deux utilisations sont correctes. En l'occurence: _"Je serai absent du lundi au jeudi"_ peut très bien être employé en parlant de la semaine prochaine. Je dirais plutôt que l'utilisation du _"de lundi à jeudi"_ parle du lundi et jeudi les plus proches de la date courante.

Answer (score 2):

Lorsqu'on utilise "à", la date ou l'heure est évidente dans le contexte dans lequel on parle alors que quand on utilise "au", il y a une indétermination, très souvent suivie d'une précision. Avec tes exemples:

> Du lundi au jeudi à 19h30.

Ici "au jeudi" fait référence à tous les jeudis de toutes les semaines, pas à un précis. Par contre, on dit "à 19h30" car ça ne désigne qu'un unique moment dans la journée.

> À jeudi !

Ici on suppose qu'il s'agit de jeudi prochain, la date ne fait aucun doute.

> Le chantier durera jusqu'à jeudi.

C'est correct mais cela implique jeudi *prochain*. (J'ai remplacé construction par chantier car c'est le terme que tu cherches).

> Le chantier durera jusqu'au jeudi.

Ici, il manque un complement. En utilisant "au", tu supposes qu'il manque des informations. Il faudrait dire par exemple:

> Le chantier durera jusqu'au jeudi 10 janvier.

En résumé :

Utilise "à" quand la date ne fait aucun doute. On suppose toujours que c'est la première occurrence (jeudi/février/Noël *prochain*).

Utilise "au" pour une date qui doit être precisée.